# UIWebView load content On demand

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, load

I have huge amount of data which load on UIWebView. So there has some issues 
1. It's take lot of time on loading 
2. On iPhone-OS3 it shows little chunk but In iPhone-OS4 it doesn't 
3. On orientation it takes much time.

So any suggestion? how can I load content On Demand Need?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:` instead of `[webView loadRequest:]`. Then implement `connection:didReceiveData:` to accumulate the data received and `connectionDidFinishLoading:` inform the user there is no more data to be loaded.